# Counting documents in partition with identical field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say I have a partition with the following schema:

```
{ type: "car", failure: "gas-pedal" }
{ type: "truck", failure: "clutch" },
{ type: "motorbike", failure: "gas-pedal" }
...
```

And let's say I want to have an efficient access to the number of occurrences of a given `failure` type (in this case would be `2`).

What would be the easiest approach?

EDIT: `type` would be primary partition key and `failure` the sorting key.

Comment: We need more detail - is failure a sort key? is type a primary key? do you have both values when you need to count occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB does not support aggregations.  DynamoDB does not have the SQL equivalent of

`select count(*) from <mytable> where <attribute> = ...`

As a NoSQL database, DynamoDB requires you to design your data model based on your application access patterns.  In this case, if your application needs a count of an attribute by type, you have a few options:

1. Perform a `scan` operation to fetch all attributes by failure type and count the number of records that get returned.  The `scan` operation should generally be avoided for common access patterns or large data sets since it will inspect every item in your database.  This can be inefficient and cost-prohibitive but is the simplest way to achieve what you want.
2. Maintain a count of failure types that you update when failures are inserted/updated.  For example, you could create a record with PK=FAILURE and SK= with a count attribute:

| PK | SK | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FAILURE | gas-pedal | 2 |
| FAILURE | clutch | 1 |

Each time you insert a record with a failure type, you'd update the count of that type in the FAILURE partition using an [atomic counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).  You could do this at the same time you insert/update the item with a `failure` attribute (e.g. in a batch or transaction operation) or using DynamoDB streams to process records that include the `failure` attribute.

Both of these approaches are a departure from how you'd do this in a SQL database, which is a common theme when working with DynamoDB and NoSQL databases.

Comment: A third method would be to have every document that failed have a failed attribute - that attribute does not exist if the document in question didnt fail. Then you can create an Index off that attribute - when you query against that attribute as the partition key in that index, you will only get back the items that have it, giving you a count. However, this has a limitation because you only get back a limited number of items at once and youd have to paginate through them to get them all, which cost additional time and resources.